# Best Enterprise Tool to Synchronize Multiple Databases/Directories to One Directory

Tags: database, directory, synchronization

I have applications storing information user information, entitlements and group authorizations across multiple directories (eDirectory, AD LDS) and databases (OUD, ODSEE, Sybase).

For phase 1, we want to synchronize the data from these different sources to one Active Directory DC. In phase 2, we will migrate the apps and decommission the sources.

What is the best enterprise tool for this job? Was consider Microsoft Identity Manager's Sync Engine. Any other good/better contenders?

Comment: You might consider posting in the software recommendations stack since this is not  truly a stack overflow question. Here is the link: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: @camba1 - Will do, thanks!